# How to delete cookies and set elements to show again?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cookies

I need a jQuery code, not JavaScript, that will delete cookies and set elements to show again.

Here is my code:

HTML:

```
<div class="recoverit"><a href="javascript:;">Recover Cookies</a></div>
```

jQuery:

```
document.cookie = elementId+ "=true; path=/; expires=Th, 31 Dec 2099 11:00:00 GMT;" + date.toUTCString();
```

Storing of the cookies works great, but now I need to remove them and "elementId" to show again on the same places.

Thanks.

Comment: jQuery *is* JavaScript

Comment: I know, but I would need this in jQuery.

Comment: `document.cookie` is not jQuery .

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458724/how-to-set-unset-cookie-with-jquery?rq=1

Comment: tried reading the docs on jquery cookie? 
https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie#readme

Comment: Yes I did, I'm not very proficient with jQuery.. Sorry guys.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
function delete_cookie(elementId) {
    document.cookie = elementId + '=;expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT;';
};
```

Or you can use jquery as others suggested.

**UPDATE** full sample as asked:

```
<html>
<script>
function setCookie(elementId) {
    document.cookie = elementId + "=true; path=/; expires=Th, 31 Dec 2099 11:00:00 GMT;";
    document.getElementById(elementId).style.display = "none";
}

function deleteCookie(elementId) {
    document.cookie = elementId + '=;expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT;';
    document.getElementById(elementId).style.display = "block";
}
</script>
<body>
<a href="#" onclick="setCookie('el1');">hide element</a>

<a href="#" onclick="deleteCookie('el1');">restore element</a>

<br>
<div id="el1">one two three...</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't want to use any plugins.. I will try this, but how do I set the element to show again without refreshing?

Comment: he asked for a jquery soloution

Comment: document.getElementById(elementId).style.display='block'  no jquery

$('#elementId').show() jquery

Comment: @Ra3IDeN but it does not want a plugin either. Downgrading my answer is not correct, since it works even if you have jquery.

Comment: Jkike, could you please elaborate more? Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand what do I have to elaborate... you ask how to show an element again, so I rekon you have it hidden at the moment. The reverse of hidden is 
 
document.getElementById(elementId).style.display='block'  or  $('#elementId').show() where elementId is the id of the html element you want to show. Of course it must exist in the page, although is hidden.

Comment: Okay, I will let you know if it works and mark your response as correct. Thanks once more.

Comment: Is there a chance you can write the entire code for this, for some reason it's not working.